# SharePoint Migration Assembly References default.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server, upgrade, 2016

I have a test site that I migrated from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2016 using the attach upgrade method. Is it normal for all of the default.aspx pages to still be referencing version 12.0.0.0 ("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0") and not version 16.0.0.0?

The UIVersion is showing 15 for everything when I run the following:

```
$sc = Get-SPSite http://<URL>; $sc.GetVisualReport() | Format-Table
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint has assembly redirection in place, so it's OK that you see 12.0.0.0 on your pages that have been migrated. As far as the `UIVersion`, the version did not increment to 16 with SharePoint 2016, which is also why you don't have to upgrade your Site Collections after attaching them to a 2016 farm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Trevor. I did some more digging and I see that some pages show version 14.0.0.0 and other show 12.0.0.0. It's almost as if during the upgrade process one of the steps I performed changed some of the pages but not others. Maybe during the visual upgrade, I don't know.